# PLSQL Converting if then to CASE stmt

Tags: plsql

Converting if then to CASE stmt. Please let me know what mistake I m making here

```
DECLARE
    salary      NUMBER;
        bonus       NUMBER;
        hdate       DATE;
    empno       NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT hiredate INTO hdate FROM emp where empno=7788 ;
    CASE hdate
            WHEN hdate > TO_DATE('01-JAN-82') THEN bonus := 500  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bonus);
            WHEN hdate > TO_DATE('23-JAN-16') THEN bonus := 1000 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bonus);
            ELSE bonus := 1500 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bonus);
    END CASE;
END;
/
```

Comment: You need to give ; in each then like `THEN bonus := 500;` no need of multiple dbms_output.put_line. You can put it in the end after completing case statement

Comment: Also, dates are written like `date '1982-01-01'`, not `TO_DATE('01-JAN-82')`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following syntax for [CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems004.htm):

```
DECLARE
    salary      NUMBER;
        bonus       NUMBER;
        hdate       DATE;
    empno       NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT sysdate INTO hdate FROM dual ;
    CASE 
            WHEN hdate > TO_DATE('01-JAN-82') THEN bonus := 500;  
            WHEN hdate > TO_DATE('23-JAN-16') THEN bonus := 1000 ;
            ELSE bonus := 1500 ;
    END CASE;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bonus);
END;
```

> Notice that the WHEN clauses can use different conditions rather than all testing the same variable or using the same operator.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps another proposition; instead of `CASE` statement in `WHERE` clause, it is rather in the `SELECT` list to deter the usage of `hdate`, thus a single SQL to achieve the desired output.

```
DECLARE
   salary    NUMBER;
   p_bonus   NUMBER;
   hdate     DATE;
   empno     NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT CASE
             WHEN hiredate > TO_DATE ('01-JAN-82') THEN 500
             WHEN hiredate > TO_DATE ('23-JAN-16') THEN 1000
             ELSE 1500
          END
     INTO p_bonus
     FROM emp
    WHERE empno = 7788;


   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_bonus);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, there are a couple of other things wrong with your case statement.

**Dates**

When you use `to_date` to explicitly convert a string into a date, you should also use a format model to describe the format of the string. By not doing so, you rely on the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter, which could well be different on different machines.

Also, years have 4 digits - use all of them, rather than make Oracle guess. Does the 2 digit year `16` mean `2016` or `1916`?

Far better to be explicit, in both cases!

Therefore, your date conditions should actually be `to_date('01-JAN-1982', 'dd-MON-yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')` and `to_date('23-JAN-2016', 'dd-MON-yyyy')`.

Note the presence of the optional third parameter - I used that because you specified the month in words, and again, your NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE parameter might not be the same on someone else's machine. Adding the third parameter means the string will be converted to a date regardless of your NLS settings.

You can avoid the use of the 3rd parameter in `to_date` by using numbers for the day, month and year, e.g. `to_date('23/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')`.

**CASE and logic short circuiting**

CASE uses logic short circuiting, meaning that when it evaluates a condition to be true, it doesn't process any further conditions.

It seems like you intend a hiredate of 23rd Feb 2017 to get a bonus of 1000, but since it meets the first condition (it's later than 1st Jan 1982), it gets a bonus of 500.

Therefore, you need to change the order of the conditions, so that the most restrictive is at the top. In your case, your procedure becomes:

```
DECLARE
  salary NUMBER;
  bonus  NUMBER;
  hdate  DATE;
  empno  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT hiredate
  INTO   hdate
  FROM   emp
  WHERE  empno=7788;

  CASE hdate
    WHEN hdate > TO_DATE('23-JAN-16') THEN bonus := 1000;
    WHEN hdate > TO_DATE('01-JAN-82') THEN bonus := 500;
    ELSE bonus := 1500 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bonus);
  END CASE;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(bonus);
END;
/
```